# Sticky header CSS when header is unknown height

Tags: css

I can see quite a lot of articles online about how to create sticky headers (ie. when the user scrolls the page, the header stays in place at the top of the window). However they all seem to imply that the header should be of a fixed height?

This is unacceptable for me. For a very simple example, on certain dates like July 4 I might want to put a USA flag in the header - which will slightly increase the height.

So how can I make a header, say all contained within a `<div class="header"> ... </div>` area, sticky - regardless of the height of the div?

Comment: JavaScript, my friend

Comment: You got the wrong idea. `position: fixed` makes a header sticky and it works with dynamic `height`

Comment: Marian, the poster has the right idea. You can do position:fixed on the header, but you need to know the height of the header to give a padding-top to whatever is below the header, else it will be covered by the header.

Comment: Maybe he has a hero image below the header and he doesn't need some padding. I can't imagine all the contexts where a fixed header could cause issues with a specific design. I simply answered his question: "how can I make a header sticky - regardless of the height of the div"

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies. user1771700 is correct. I don't want the rest of the page to be covered by the header. I just want the header to stay in place, and the rest of the page to be scrollable.

Comment: As Wes Foster said, you can use javascript. You can do something like this: create your header, and after the user scrolls for 300px or whatever value, add a new class to the header and use that class to add `position:fixed` to the header. That way you won't have to worry about padding as user1771700 said.

If still in doubt, have a look at a premium theme, and try to replicate the way they made the header/menu sticky. GL!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to be late to the party, but this can be done without any Javascript at all. This may be aesthetically unpleasing, an offense against god and man, but it does work! The trick is to put precisely the same content in two div's:

```
<div id="fbanner">Here's your banner content</div>
<div id="banner">Here's your banner content</div>
<div id="restofpage">Here's the stuff on the rest of your page</div>
```

Then provide some CSS:

```
#fbanner {
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
}
#banner {
     visibility: hidden;
}
```

So, no matter what the content is, even if it's text that line-wraps in a narrow viewport, both div's will be the same height, and the hidden one will take up the space needed to keep the rest of the page content from disappearing under the banner until you scroll.

You might find that you have to do some tinkering with margins, but that's a small price to pay if you want to avoid yet another jQuery "solution."

Comment: This is really clever.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use jquery for this. jquery get the height of the header dynamically and put the padding top on bellow the heard div.

For example

HTML

```
<html>
<head>test</head>
<body>

<header>
<div class="example"> Test</div>
</header>

<div class="sample-content">
Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content Test Content
</div>
```

CSS

```
header{width:100%; position:fixed;}
```

JQUERY

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
  // this gets dynamic height of your header
  var sticky_header = $('header').height();

// apply tha dynamic height to your div after header for margin-top so it not covered by sticky header  
  $('.sample-content').css('margin-top', sticky_header + 'px' );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a header that is not a fixed pixel height - depending on what the other department decides to put in the banner in the content management system, the height of the header will change.

So I did just as **@MisterNeutron** answer suggested and created a **2nd header (invisible)** but my header is pretty Massive, so instead of duplicating the html I just clone the header DOM element with Javascript.

```
    var visibleHeader = document.querySelector('.fixed-top').cloneNode(true);
    var invisibleHeader = document.querySelector('.fixed-top');
    invisibleHeader.style.visibility = 'hidden';//take up space, but be hidden.
    invisibleHeader.style.position = 'relative';//un-fix
    document.querySelector('body').insertBefore(visibleHeader, invisibleHeader);
```

The header it's self is directly inside the body so the html ends up looking like this:

`<body>
    <div class="fixed-top">
         ... rest of header html ...
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-top" style="visibility: hidden; position: relative;">
         ... rest of header html ...
    </div>
    ... rest of page goes here ...
</body>`

Note that if you have any elements with Id's in the header, this will create 2 of the element with same ID, but if you make sure the Real header is Above, I believe when you query for it, it will always grab the one you want.